# EMR spark step and merge output into one file

Tags: apache-spark-sql, emr, parquet

I am trying emr spark step. I have an input s3 directory. Which have multiple files: f1,f2,f3

I am adding spark step like this:

```
aws emr --region us-west-2 add-steps  --cluster-id foo --steps '[{"Args":["spark-submit","--deploy-mode","cluster","--class","JsonToDataToParquetJob","s3://foo/My.assembly.jar","s3://inputDir/","output/"],"Type":"CUSTOM_JAR","ActionOnFailure":"CONTINUE","Jar":"command-runner.jar","Properties":"","Name":"Spark application"}]'
```

Which has following code:

```
delimitedData.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(output)
```

The problem I am facing is:
I am having multiple output files. But what I am looking for is single output file in the directory. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, an output file is generated per partition.
You should be able to achieve what you want by doing a `repartition(1)`.

like this:
`repartition(1).write().mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(output);`